# Python 3.7 Doesn't import an another python file

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

So firstly, I use the first file to import the second using `import second_file` then in the second file,
I import the first file with the same way and it works and I also import the third file from the first file BUT when I try to import the first file from the third it doesn't work

So: file1 ----> `import second_file`
file 2 ---->  `import first_file`
file1 ----> `import third_file`
file 3 ----> `import first_file` **THAT IMPORT DOESN'T WORK**

Comment: This is an example of a cyclic import, where two (or in this case three) modules import each other. There are ways to deal with these in python, but it depends on the situation. In general they should be avoided and in the vast majority of cases its possible to restructure the code in such a way the cyclic import is avoided entirely.

Comment: I found a temp solution using runpy and runpy.run_module(mod_name="")

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
from first_file import *
from Second_file import *
```

Comment: Ok, I will try! Thanks

Comment: Well I get warning "unused import"